# Why does SQL Server throw "divide by 0" in running stored procedure and will not happen in independent statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This code will throw a "divide by 0" error in running the stored procedure only, and will not happen in independent statement.

I want to know what the difference between executing as a stored procedure and common statement lead to this situation.

The table `PPB_PBExecuteLine` has about 200 records and has 67 records with Qty is 0, but only do the select will not get Qty = 0 record in specified situation

Here is the statement:

```
--exec PPB_P_ReCalcActaulExeSUMToPB 1001603230260241,-1,1001605170110011

Create Procedure PPB_P_ReCalcActaulExeSUMToPB
    @Org Bigint,
    @CBS Bigint,
    @ProjectIDs Nvarchar(max) 
with recompile
as
Begin
    Declare @SQL Nvarchar(Max)

    If Object_ID('tempdb..#Projects') is not null
            drop table #Projects;

    Create table #Projects (ID bigint null);

    If(@ProjectIDs != '')
    Begin
        Set @SQL = 'insert into #Projects (ID)' + 'select ' + replace(@ProjectIDs,',',' as ID union all select ') 
        Exec sp_executesql @SQL
    End

    If object_id('tempdb..#ProjectBudget_Detail_DiffCost') Is Not Null
        Drop Table #ProjectBudget_Detail_DiffCost;

    --*******this statement
    Select 
        B.ID as ExecuteLine,
        SUM(C.ExecuteCost - (B.OutExeCome / B.Qty) * C.Qty) as DiffCost
    Into 
        #ProjectBudget_Detail_DiffCost
    From 
        PPB_PBExecute A
    Inner Join 
        PPB_PBExecuteLine B on A.ID = B.PBExecute
    Inner Join 
        PPB_PBExecuteDetial C on C.PBExecuteLine = B.ID 
    Where 
        A.Org = @Org 
        and (A.CBS = @CBS or @CBS <= 0) 
        and (A.Project in (select ID from #Projects) or @ProjectIDs = '')
    Group by 
        B.ID

    Update A 
    Set A.DiffCost = B.DiffCost 
    From PPB_PBExecuteLine as A 
    Inner Join #ProjectBudget_Detail_DiffCost as B on A.ID = B.ExecuteLine
   --and more 
End
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your stored procedure, there is only one line that causes the exception and this is in

```
SUM(C.ExecuteCost - (B.OutExeCome / B.Qty) * C.Qty ) as DiffCost
```

When `B.Qty` is 0 then it will throw the exception. However, this can be prevented by adding extra validation in the column with a `CASE` expression.

```
SUM(C.ExecuteCost - (B.OutExeCome / (CASE WHEN B.Qty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE B.Qty END) * C.Qty) as DiffCost
```

Comment: Yes,it will solve this problem.But,I'm just confused about why same statements have different result.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated to explain.  First, though, use `nullif()` to eliminate the possibility of the problem:

```
Select B.ID as ExecuteLine,
       SUM( C.ExecuteCost-(B.OutExeCome/nullif(B.Qty, 0))*C.Qty ) as DiffCost
```

(Or you might want some other logic.)

One possibility is that `B.Qty` is, in fact, `0` causing the problem.  Let me speculate that this isn't the problem, because you are seeing the error in one place but not the other.

This leads to the possibility that the `0` is on a row that is filtered out.  How can you get an error on a row that is filtered out?  Well, SQL Server does not guarantee the order of processing of expressions.  In fact, it can push some calculations before the filtering in the `where`.

Voila!  An error.

Why would this occur in one place but not the other?  That would be due to differing execution plans.  Perhaps the version in the stored procedure was cached and the optimal plan has changed.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser.It seem to be caused by the order changed.It's not a serious mistake,I should just remeber it.

Comment: @Kegegege - Erland Sommarskog (IIRC) described these as [illogical errors](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) (all authorship info seems to have been lost since this was moved to azure.com). There is a *logical processing order* that SQL engines should follow. They are free to re-arrange the actual processing order, *so long as they produce the same results*. However, MS have taken the first part (re-arrange processing) and produce different results (error vs result set). No sign they'll change it though.

Comment: illogical errors,a very appropriate expression.MS may want to be more rigorous,and also brings more work.I though I have known the reason of it,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In math dividing by zero is undefined. So, in SQL Server, would be also undefined, which mean it is not an integer nor NULL.

In your stored procedure,

```
SUM(C.ExecuteCost - (B.OutExeCome / B.Qty) * C.Qty) as DiffCost
```

if the B.Qty = 0, an error will be thrown, so you need to take care of that by using one of these methods :

**USING CASE:**

You could use CASE senario and replace the value Zero with a number or NULL. Here I'll be replace it with a number 1.

```
(CASE WHEN B.Qty <> 0 THEN B.Qty ELSE 1 )
```

**USING NULLIF**

This is the fastest way to do it, which will return NULL if the value equals to Zero.

```
NULLIF(B.Qty, 0)
```

**ARITHABORT and ANSI_WARNINGS**

You can set ARITHABORT and ANSI_WARNINGS OFF, with this, SQL server will return NULL with a Zero division.

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```